# Netbeans java program has java.lang.classnotFoundException for jdbc using mysql (jar file is included)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I haven't even started with the program but the Class.forName() is giving an error for mysql, as can be seen in the screenshot.
The error is java.lang.ClassnotFoundException, even though I included external jar file 
I am pretty sure I am missing something trivial, all answers on internet tell me to include jar file but I dont know where I am wrong.[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZjNZ.png)

[My Code, please ignore other errors its not even started yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKZOm.png)

Comment: Don't post code as a screenshot. Also using `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary to load a JDBC driver since 2006. I have voted to close with the canonical duplicate, but as your post lacks a clear indication of the full error, the problem could just as well be that you **forgot to catch + handle or declare the `ClassNotFoundException`**.

Comment: Thank you it was the try block error, 
But I was going to add catch statement later AND there was a separate error for try block, so I thought these were different errors
Anyway catch statement solved my problem thanks
If this thread needs to be deleted then I am ok with it